# Wpf Textbox UpdateSourceTrigger doesn't update the source

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple Window with a TextBox

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Configurator.ConfiguratorWindow"
    x:Name="ConfigWindow" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

<TextBox x:Name="DescriptionTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=Description, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>

</Window>
```

in the code behind

```
public partial class ConfiguratorWindow : Window
{
    public ConfiguratorWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private static DependencyProperty DescriptionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Description", typeof(string), typeof(ConfiguratorWindow), new PropertyMetadata());

    public string Description
        {
            get { return GetValue(DescriptionProperty).ToString(); }
            set {
                    SetValue(DescriptionProperty, value);
                    _actual_monitor.Description = value;
                }
        }
}
```

the graphic is updating right, but when i change the text in the textbox and lose focus it doesn't update the source property.

What is wrong?

Comment: You should use dependency property changed callback to track value changing. `new PropertyMetadata(null, DescriptionPropertyChangedCallback)`

Comment: @adminSoftDK Carefully read the XAML again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<Window x:Class="Configurator.ConfiguratorWindow"
         xmlns:myWindow="clr-namespace:YourNamespace"
x:Name="ConfigWindow" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

<TextBox x:Name="DescriptionTextBox" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type myWindow}}, Path=Description, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
```

```
public partial class ConfiguratorWindow : Window
{
public ConfiguratorWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

private static DependencyProperty DescriptionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Description", typeof(string), typeof(ConfiguratorWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null, CallBack);

 private static void callback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var foo = d as ConfiguratorWindow ;
       all you need to do, you can do here
    }

public string Description
    {
        get { return GetValue(DescriptionProperty).ToString(); }
        set { SetValue(DescriptionProperty, value);}
    }
}
```

But it would be much easier to just have a View Model and bind to property there.

Comment: What is the `xmlns` declaration good for? It isn't used anywhere.

Comment: @Clemens it just cut of part of my code due to format :P

Comment: The Text binding was ok, because the Window's DataContext was bound to the window instance.

Comment: @Clemens you are right, but what if he wants to change his datacontext to something else later, this way it will see it regardless.

Comment: "but what if he wants to ..." What? Please do not invent new problems, try to address the question (what you did by mentioning the missing PropertyChangedCallback).

Comment: @Clemens so this way will work, I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: Ok, i understand. I miss the callback method.
Can you explain why i have to use the a View Model?

Comment: @ek32 There are lots of reasons to go with MVVM, I guess the main one in this case is simplicity. You can then simply bind your text to Description property as you tried to do and it will work, without any need for dp, callbacks etc, you will need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged though. Janne answer below has some links in it, I suggest you check them out :).

Answer (score 1):

DependencyProperties are used for UserControls rather than ViewModel type bindings.

You should

1. Create a ConfigurationWindowViewModel (Read about [MVVM](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100175/Model-View-ViewModel-MVVM-Explained)) and implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. Create a Property Description that utilizes the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. Create a new instance of that view model to be set to the DataContext of your ConfigurationWindow.

Answer (score 1):

The getter and setter of the CLR wrapper of a dependency property must not contain any other code than GetValue and SetValue. The reason is explained in the [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563(v=vs.110).aspx) article on MSDN.

So remove the `_actual_monitor.Description = value;` assignment from the setter and add a PropertyChangedCallback to react on property value changes:

```
public partial class ConfiguratorWindow : Window
{
    public ConfiguratorWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private static DependencyProperty DescriptionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Description", typeof(string), typeof(ConfiguratorWindow),
        new PropertyMetadata(DescriptionPropertyChanged));

    public string Description
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DescriptionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DescriptionProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void DescriptionPropertyChanged(
        DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ConfiguratorWindow obj = d as ConfiguratorWindow;
        obj._actual_monitor.Text = (string)e.newValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: You still have `_actual_monitor.Description = value;` in the setter of the CLR property wrapper. It shouldn't be there, because the setter won't be called when the property is set in XAML.

Comment: @Clemens actually you are right, I didnt care of what was written above.I just cut and paste in order to explain that callback method could solve the problem.I edit the code.Thanks.

Comment: It also doesn't make sense to set DescriptionTextBox.Text in the callback, because the Text property is already bound to the Description property. What OP actually wants is to set `obj._actual_monitor.Description = (string)e.NewValue;` (assuming that _actual_monitor is a class member).

Comment: Thank you @FreeMan, but the adminSoftDK 's answer was faster and it's right choose his answer like correct